# Change tabBar height in Swift 5 for IOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, ios13, swift5

I need to change the `UITabBar` height to 95. I can do that in the older version of iOS Swift. This is my code that work in the older version.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    tabBar.frame.size.height = 95
    tabBar.frame.origin.y = view.frame.height - 95

    menuButton.frame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height - tabBar.frame.size.height - 10
    shadowBtn.frame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height - tabBar.frame.size.height - 15
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try it in **viewDidLayoutSubviews**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    tabBar.frame.size.height = 95
    tabBar.frame.origin.y = view.frame.height - 95
}
```

Comment: hello ... this code is currect but when i want to hide tabbar when i push to another view controller tabbar hide with delay ...

Comment: @kuldeep, I look wired in iPhone X devices

Answer (score 1):

I am using following approach

```
extension UIWindow {
    static var key: UIWindow? {
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            return UIApplication.shared.windows.first { $0.isKeyWindow }
        } else {
            return UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        }
    }
}

extension UITabBar {
    override open func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        super.sizeThatFits(size)
        guard let window = UIWindow.key else {
            return super.sizeThatFits(size)
        }
        var sizeThatFits = super.sizeThatFits(size)
        sizeThatFits.height = window.safeAreaInsets.bottom + <# Height #>
        return sizeThatFits
    }
}
```

Or if you don't like to create extension, create UITabBar Subclass and then override this method.

When you are changing height of Tab bar with `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, you are forgetting the Safe Area. You will have to set addition Safe Area Inset via `self.additionalSafeAreaInsets` and by doing so this inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and `viewWillLayoutSubview`, Tab bar will shift upwards (because you have added additional inset). If you don't care about Auto Layout and Safe Area, then you are fine to go with `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews`